ubuntu black screen but ssh works
system info:
kernel:
uname -a
Linux ripper101 5.15.0-107-generic #117-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 26 12:26:49 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

nvdia card:
hwinfo --gfxcard --short
graphics card:                                                  
                       nVidia GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070]

Primary display adapter: #52

distro:
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS \n \l

nvdia drivers:
ubuntu-drivers list
nvidia-driver-550, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-550-generic)
nvidia-driver-535-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-generic)
nvidia-driver-470, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic)
nvidia-driver-520, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-520)
nvidia-driver-525, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-525)
nvidia-driver-515, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-515)
nvidia-driver-545, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-545)
nvidia-driver-390, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic)
nvidia-driver-535, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic)
nvidia-driver-450-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-450-server-generic)
nvidia-driver-470-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-470-server-generic)
nvidia-driver-418-server, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-418-server)

x11 logs
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    28.695] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:41:00.0: -19
[    28.695] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    28.695] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    28.696] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[    28.697] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    28.697] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    28.704] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER

kernel messages
sudo dmesg | grep nvidia
[    7.007888] audit: type=1400 audit(1715979079.054:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=1373 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.007893] audit: type=1400 audit(1715979079.054:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=1373 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.023052] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    7.023066] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    7.120343] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    7.134353] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 511
[    7.135440] nvidia 0000:41:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    7.277506] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  470.239.06  Sat Feb  3 06:03:51 UTC 2024
[    7.285749] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00004100] Loading driver
[    7.580838] caller os_map_kernel_space.part.0+0x83/0xb0 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
[    8.055386] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:41:00.0 on minor 0
[    8.089113] nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
[    8.097013] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 509.

idk what i tried.
maybe simply apt upgrade -y triggered the issue. but im not sure.
Maybe the tainted kernal and the kernel module verfication is a hint?
Any help is appreciated
hint0:
reinstalling of driver apt purge *nvidia*, apt autoremove, apt autoclean, apt -f install, apt-add-repository -r ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa, apt install nvidia-driver-460
leads to this normal outpout
libnvidia-decode-550:amd64 (550.54.15-0ubuntu1) wird eingerichtet ...
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550 (550.54.15-0ubuntu1) wird eingerichtet ...
nvidia-dkms-550 (550.54.15-0ubuntu1) wird eingerichtet ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Loading new nvidia-550.54.15 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-107-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-107-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-107-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-107-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-107-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-107-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-peermem.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-107-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...
libnvidia-encode-550:amd64 (550.54.15-0ubuntu1) wird eingerichtet ...
libx11-6:i386 (2:1.7.5-1ubuntu0.3) wird eingerichtet ...
nvidia-driver-550 (550.54.15-0ubuntu1) wird eingerichtet ...
libxext6:i386 (2:1.3.4-1build1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-fbc1-550:i386 (550.54.15-0ubuntu1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-gl-550:i386 (550.54.15-0ubuntu1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-decode-550:i386 (550.54.15-0ubuntu1) wird eingerichtet ...
libnvidia-encode-550:i386 (550.54.15-0ubuntu1) wird eingerichtet ...
Trigger für bamfdaemon (0.5.6+22.04.20220217-0ubuntu1) werden verarbeitet ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Trigger für desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) werden verarbeitet ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-107-generic
Trigger für gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.7) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für man-db (2.10.2-1) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) werden verarbeitet ...

dkms status
nvidia/550.54.15, 5.15.0-107-generic, x86_64: installed

hint1:
apt-get install -V nvidia-kernel-source-550-open cuda-drivers-550
reboot
dmesg | grep nvidia
messes kernel log
`  391.138186] nvidia: probe of 0000:41:00.0 failed with error -1
[  391.138428] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 510
[  391.269652] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510
[  391.271158] nvidia 0000:41:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=none,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
               NVRM: nvidia.ko because it does not include the required GPU
               NVRM: www.nvidia.com.


did not fix it.
tysm

Please ask here instead: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Either your video card is busted or you are using the wrong driver for it.  Booting with kernel command line option nomodeset should at least get you video, but without the driver.
